# MVC3 model set up - Code First EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a list of train journeys (among other things) in MVC, using code first Entity Framework and wondered how I could map foreign keys for the stations.  The `Journey` model/table will have a `DepartureStationID` and an `ArrivalStationID` which will be foreign keys linking to one table/model, called `Station`.

Here is the code for both these models:

```
public class Station
{        
    public int StationID { get; set; }
    public string StationName { get; set; }
    public string StationLocation { get; set; }
}

public class Journey
{
    public int JourneyID { get; set; }
    public int DepartureID { get; set; }
    public int ArrivalID { get; set; }
    public int OperatorID  { get; set; }
    public string JourneyCode { get; set; }

    public virtual Operator Operator { get; set; }
    public virtual Station DepartureStation { get; set; }   
    public virtual Station ArrivalStation { get; set; }    
}
```

There is another foreign key value in there, namely `Operator` and that has mapped successfully, but the departure and arrivals haven't, and return null values in the view:  `(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartureStation.StationName)`.
When I looked in the database, there had been two additional fields created by EF:

```
DepartureStation_StationID
ArrivalStation_StationID
```

And the SQL relationship was between the station table and the two fields above, rather than `DepartureID` and `ArrivalID`

So, my question is - Do I need to do something different in the model when referencing the same table for two fields?  I don't know why those additional fields were added so I presume I've set up the model incorrectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, here's the same thing with fluent configuration.

```
public class MyDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Journey> Journeys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Operator> Operators { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Station> Stations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Journey>()
            .HasRequired(j => j.DepartureStation)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(j => j.DepartureID);

        builder.Entity<Journey>()
            .HasRequired(j => j.ArrivalStation)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(j => j.ArrivalId);

        // ... Same thing for operator ...

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Edit: To address your above comment about the cascade delete, you can add `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` after `.HasForeignKey()` and that might help (although you'll then have to delete Journey records manually)

Comment: Hi Leniency,  Thanks very much - this solved it for me.  By adding what you'd written, plus the option of                `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`, that sorted the initial error and the Cascade issue. Excellent.

Answer (score 3):

Add the folowing attributes on your navigation properties :

```
public class Journey
{
    public int JourneyID { get; set; }
    public int DepartureID { get; set; }
    public int ArrivalID { get; set; }
    public int OperatorID  { get; set; }
    public string JourneyCode { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OperatorID")]
    public virtual Operator Operator { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartureID")]
    public virtual Station DepartureStation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ArrivalID")]
    public virtual Station ArrivalStation { get; set; }
}
```

And of course you need to regenerate your database in order to apply the new configuration.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Haythem,  Thanks - this looks good.  Unfortunately it's introduced this error:  `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'Journey_DepartureStation' on table 'Journeys' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.`  I'll go and look into this error and try and figure it out out and report back...

Comment: See my post below for a possible fix. The multiple cascade path error is an annoying one with SQL Server - they're very conservative about that whereas other databases will just delete regardless.  It's probably coming from having two properties in Journey pointing to the Station table.  Remove the cascade-on-deletes and just handle it manually.